# Proof for number of internal nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, trie, compression, induction

I was reading about compressed tries and read the following:

a compressed trie is a tree which has L leaves and every internal node in the trie has at least 2 children.

Then the author wrote that a tree with L leaves such that every internal node has alteast 2 children, has atmost L-1 internal nodes. I am really confused why this is true.

Can somebody offer a inductive proof for it?

Comment: That is REALLY easy ... have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Also, do you mean "trie" or "tree"? They are different datastructures.

Comment: @Marcin - A trie is a special kind of tree, for this question the differences don't matter.

Comment: @Marcin: He means tree in a graph-theoretic sense. And it is true that any trie is a tree in that sense.

Comment: @jpalecek: Then I shouldn't go around implementing tries - I thought they were the same as skiplists.

Comment: @Marcin: Maybe up my question if it helped clarify your doubt :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inductive proof:**

we will prove it by induction on `L` - the number of leaves in the tree. 

**base:** a tree made out of 1 leaf is actually a tree with only a root. It has 0 internal nodes, and the claim is true.

**assume** the claim is true for a compressed tree with L leaves.

**Step:** let T be a tree with L+1 leaves. choose an arbitrary leaf, let it be l, and trim it.

In order to make the tree compressed again - you need to make l's father a leaf [if l's father has more then 2 sons including l, skip this step]. We do it by giving it the same value as l's brother, and trimming the brother.

Now you have a tree T' with L leaves. 

By induction: T' has at most L-1 internal nodes.

so, T had L-1+1 = L internal nodes, and L+1 leaves, at most.

Q.E.D.

**alternative proof:**

a binary tree with L leaves has L-1 internal nodes (1 + 2 + 4 + ... + L/2 = L-1)

Since at "worst case" you have a binary tree [every internal node has at least 2 sons!], then you cannot have more then L-1 internal nodes!

Comment: @Nemo: if the father has more then 2 sons including l, then by trimming l, and doing nothing else, there are L leaves in the new Tree [let it be T'], and by induction hypothesis, there are no more then L-1 inner nodes in T'. We did not trim any inner nodes, so there are no more then L-1 inner nodes in T as well. This case is trivial and not interesting, so I skipped it. about alternative proof: It is a guideline to a proof. proving that binary case is worst case is not difficult as well.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake.  Need to wake up before commenting.

Comment: Can you explain: a binary tree with L leaves has L-1 internal nodes (1 + 2 + 4 + ... + L/2 = L-1) ?

Comment: @crisron This is [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with `a=1, r=2`. Calculating the formulas for `a_k` (number of nodes at depth `k` from the root) and `S_{k-1}` (sum of internal nodes for that level `k`), gives `S_k-1 = (1-2^(k-1))/(1-2) = 2^(k-1) -1`, and `a_k = 1*2^(k-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try drawing a tree with L internal nodes, where every node has 2 children and there are L leaves. If you see why this is impossible, it won't be hard to figure out why it does work for L-1 internal nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'll have a go.

Define trees for a start:

```
T_0 = { Leaf }

T_i = T_i-1 union { Node(c1, ..., cn) | n >= 1 && ci in T_i-1 }

Trees = sum T_i
```

Now, the (sketch) proof of your assertion.

1. It is easy to check it for `T_0`
2. For `T_i`: if `t \in T_i` it is either in `T_i-1` or in the new elements. In the former case, use IH. In the latter case check the assertion (simple: if `ci`s have `L_i` leaves, `t` has `L = L_1 + ... + L_n` leaves. It also hase no more than `L_1 - 1 + L_2 - 1 + ... + L_n - 1 + 1` inner nodes (by IH for children, +1 for self). Because we assume each inner node has at least two children (that's the fact from the trie definition), it is no more than `L_1 + l_2 + ... + L_n - 2 + 1 = L - 1`).
3. By induction, if the assertion holds for `t in T_i` for all `i`, it holds for `t in Trees`.

Comment: Don't feed the help vampires!